# Infinite "entering" loop when opening a new terminal in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

When i want to open a new terminal in VSCode, it is unusable. It's like it keeps pressing the "Enter" key.

[image: My terminal]

It continues until it crashes.

If you have any idea on how to fix this i'll take it !

I'm on windows 10, i've already reinstalled VSCode twice et turn off and on my pc 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, uninstalling PowerShell helped.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the VSCode cache folder worked for me.

To find your cache folder locations, if you're using windows, you can write in the address of the folder:
%APPDATA%\Code\User\workspaceStorage
and / or :
%APPDATA%\Code\User\globalStorage

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions here didn't work for me.

What did work:

- Press Ctrl-Shift-P
- Type to search: Terminal: Select default profile
- Click this option
- select "Command Prompt (cmd)"

This will set CMD as the default terminal app and will eliminate the endless loop appearing in PowerShell.

If you still need PowerShell, write "powershell" in the CMD window and hit [enter]